# check if checkbox is checked before submit form in MVC C# and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

at first I had this MVC View that show a list of specific records from database, this is the code and as you can see there is a checkbox column

```
 <tbody>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.numero_documento)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre_accion_formativa)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre_empresa)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="code" value="@item.numero_documento" +"a" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
```

and when press the submit button it makes a validation that at least one checkbox has to be checked, like this

```
$("#btn-agrupar").click(function (e) {
    if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') === true)
        $("#FormAgrupar").submit();
    else {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
        }
        else {
            e.returnValue = false;
            $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
        }
    }
});
```

and used to work but now I do have to added another checkbox column and use jQuery to send to a specific controller the info in the form, this is the code of the view

```
<tbody>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.numero_documento)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre_accion_formativa)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre_empresa)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="@item.numero_documento" +"a" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="code" value="@item.numero_documento" +"a" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
```

and this is the code of my jQuery, the problem is that now it doesn´t validate if at least one checkbox is checked for none of the checkbox columns, could you help me and tell me the problem?

```
 $("#btn-agrupar").click(function () {
            if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') === true) {
                var form = $("#FormAgrupar");
                form.attr("action", "@Url.Action("RealizarAgrupacion","Home")");
                form.submit();
            }
            else {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
                }
                else {
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#btn-eliminar").click(function () {
            if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') === true) {
                var form = $("#FormAgrupar");
                form.attr("action", "@Url.Action("Index","Contact")");
                form.submit();
            }
            else {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
                }
                else {
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
                }
            }
        });
```

this is the code of the buttons in my form

```
<input type="button" value="Cancelar" id="btn-cancelar" class="btn btn-danger" />
                        <input type="button" value="Eliminar Solicitudes" id="btn-eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" />
                        <input type="button" value="Agrupar Solicitudes" id="btn-agrupar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you seem to have an issue in differentiating the two check box.You can try referencing the checkbox using it's name and see it that helps.

For example:

```
if ($("input[name='delete']").is(':checked') === true) {
    //Do something
}
if ($("input[name='code']").is(':checked') === true) {
    //Do something
}
```

To check all the checkboxes in the view, use prop function

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: your answer did work for me, just a question, how can I check all the chechkecd checkboxes of the view?

Comment: @PabloTobar Check for the latest edit. If my answer helped you please mark the answer correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `e` event param in

```
$("#btn-agrupar").click(function () ...
```

should be:

```
$("#btn-agrupar").click(function (e) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems both the checkbox columns don't have any difference. You can specify some html attribute like aria-describedby attribute. For example
For the first Checkbox aria-describedby="Delete" and for the second one aria-describedby="code" like below

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.numero_documento)
       </td>
       <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre_accion_formativa)
       </td>
       <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre_empresa)
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="delete" aria-describedby="Delete" value="@item.numero_documento" +"a" />
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="code" aria-describedby="Code" value="@item.numero_documento" +"a" />
       </td>
     </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

And it would be better to check the length of the checkboxes which are checked because you are saying atleast one checkbox can be checked means all are not mandatory to check. In that situation try to change the code as following.

```
$("#btn-agrupar").click(function (e) {
            if ($("input[aria-describedby='Delete']").is(':checked').length) {
                var form = $("#FormAgrupar");
                form.attr("action", "@Url.Action("RealizarAgrupacion","Home")");
                form.submit();
            }
            else {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
                }
                else {
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
                }
            }
        });
```

If the above code works change the code in the button click code also.

Comment: hello, with this code will be possible to check sall of the checkboxes? because there may be ten records but the user only checked five of them, could you please help

Comment: This code will give you only the checkboxes which are checked only.